# How to open the bronze port at first floor?

Tags: legend-of-grimrock

I just finished the first floor and found this big bronze door. I have no idea how to open it, do you have any hints?

> I found a strange small rock on the right wall, but nothing happens when I click it.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is another "strange small rock" in the room. Keep looking at the walls for it (as you should look for them throughout the game).

Answer (score 3):

[DJ Pirtu's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/62122/3062) is absolutely correct. There are two switches, and both must be pressed.

For anyone having trouble finding them, I've marked them on the map.

[image]